# In golang, how to return a slice of type int from a function to another function?

Tags: go

I have used channels to communicate..

```
   b := make([]int,0)  //This is the slice I have created.
```

I was appending values to the slice and I want to transfer the final slice stored in b to be returned to another function.. I have used this code..

```
   slic := make(chan int)
   go func() { slic <- input()} ()
   slice := <-slic
   fmt.Println(slice)
```

I am getting this error:"can't use b (type []int) as type int in return argument."

Comment: So does the input() function return a slice of ints, or a single int?

Answer (score 3):

Change your chan make to this:

```
make(chan []int)
```

Or select an index of your []int to send on your `chan int`.

Either way `int` and `[]int` are distinct types, as `chan int` and `chan []int` are.